# Icon spacing and monitor disordered on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, icons, desktop, desktop-icons

this morning I switched on my laptop (with a second monitor) and my icons on the desktop were disordered, they had a too long spacing (width and height) and they were on my second monitor. I searched on Google and I went in Regedit, I changed IconSpacing and IconVerticalSpacing to -1125. Now it is fine, they are in the right order (even though I think they are too little now...), but they still go on my second monitor. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check if Windows now thinks that your second monitor is the primary ([link](https://windowsreport.com/change-primary-monitor/)).

Comment: @harrymc no he doesn’t, if i try to switch primary monitors, the icons automatically go on the second one

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I pluuged my second monitor and rearrange my icons. Now when I plug it or unplug it, it stays to the same place.